# setup phpBB3 for use on local network

Tags: php, forum, phpbb, lan

I want to implement a forum for my company, because of some information security I can't use a web hosting server. So please give me some guide to setup a phpBB3 forum for **using on Local Network (LAN)**.
Assume that I have a PC for being server machine and any software needed (Windows server 2008 or Ubuntu server, Apache, MySQL 5, PHP 5 ..)
Many thanks!

Comment: Be aware that current php binaries (5.3) are compiled as vc9; therefore you may need to find a vc9 compiled version of Apache

Comment: Did you try the regular install guide on the PHPBB3 website? Did something specific not work? Either way, it's really probably more of a question for serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Copy all the phpbb files to your chosen directory in wamp/www. Add the vhost ip and port to the php.ini, Open the local port on router. 
You should be able to access from any authorized pc on the network.

OK thats the short version. More detail here. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,62212

[phpbb](/questions/tagged/phpbb)[phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3)[wamp](/questions/tagged/wamp)[wampserver](/questions/tagged/wampserver)[localhost](/questions/tagged/localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Or use [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/).
Adter installing EasyPHP extract phpBB into the www directory in EasyPHP folder (or to a subfolder) and go to http://127.0.0.1/ (or http://127.0.0.1:8080 [not sure which one is the default]).

Comment: thanks all for reply, but I want to **use** not for develop. So I can't *just* use WAMPP setups.
Someday, I'm learning about setup web server and stuffs to handle all.

Comment: phpBB requires a database and php libraries. You will need some sort of server emulation software to use if not using a webserver!

Comment: If you just want to use, buy yourself a web-server (from a web hosting company) and put it up there.